# tkinter will not recognize image data in base64 encoded string

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I changed from Python 3.4 to Python 2.7, and while debugging my script I found the interpreter unable to read a base64 graphic encoded in a string. I wanted to use the encoded image as a background for a tkinter canvas like so, but I am unable to do so now as I had been with Python 3.4:

```
background="""
iVBORw0KGgoAAA #....continues
"""

photo = tk.PhotoImage(data=background)
width, height = photo.width(), photo.height()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=width, height=height, bd=-2)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor="nw")
```

When I run the script, I get this error:

```
>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 31, in <module>
    photo = tk.PhotoImage(data=background)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 3323, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 3279, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize image data
```

Comment: I think this may be [Issue #21580](http://bugs.python.org/issue21580), but I didn't test it. This [was merged to the 2.7 branch](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/818989a48e96/) after the 2.7.8 release; which is why it isn't in the 2.7 release yet... Why are you going from 3.4 to 2.7 anyway?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Oh, I see. So I should patch my version of Python then? I switched from 3.4 because it was too much of a hassle for me compile a stand alone .exe which is basically the whole point of programming simple apps.

Comment: I'm not *sure* this is the issue (which is why I posted it as a comment, and not an answer), but yeah, you could try it. However, I would recommend that you try to solve your problems with Python 3.4 & making an .exe file (ask a question about it!), going back to Python 2.7 doesn't seem like a very good solution to me, and also seems to introduce different problems (ie. this one) ... But it's your call of course.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Everyone seems to be using 2.7 and I've had a lot of compatibility issues with third party libraries. For example I couldn't use PyIsntaller and py2exe didn't support tkinter. I tried cx_freeze but had some issues I don't remember well. I was even stupid enough to try freeze (which is for unix/linux) or to compile my script into a .c file with cython and use GCC or MSVC compilers... I like how simple PyInstaller is. Could you briefly explain how I apply this patch? Thanks.

Comment: I've had no problems at all migration from 2.7 to 3.4 with cx_Freeze for the one script that I support for Windows ... In any case, Python 3 is the future, and Python 2 is the past ([see this page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3)). You will need to migrate to 3 *sometime*... You can apply the patch in several ways; I would just clone the hg source, and checkout the `v2.7.9rc1` tag... Maybe there are also binaries somewhere. I don't know how to compile this on Windows (I've never developed for Windows much).

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out. So you would just copy/paste [these](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/818989a48e96) files and/or source code into their their respective directories in the python folder? What do you mean by check out the `v2.7.9rc1` tag?

Comment: The 2.7.9 release candidate was released yesterday or today.  It will have the #21580 patch. Give it a try.  (And I agree that 3.4 to 2.7 is a regression unless you really have to.)

Comment: @TerryJanReedy The problem is I can't bundle into a stand alone executable without downgrading.