# How do I use the base64 encoded image string in Tkinter label?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, base64, pyinstaller

I am writing a tkinter program that utilises some JPG files for its background. However, I have found that when the script is converted to an .exe file using "pyinstaller", the images used for tkinter windows are not compiled/added to the .exe file.

Therefore, I have decided to hardcode the image in the Python script so that there is no external dependency. For this purpose, I have done the following things:

```
import base64
base64_encodedString= ''' b'hAnNH65gHSJ ......(continues...) '''
datas= base64.b64decode(base64_encodedString)
```

The above code is used for decoding the base 64 encoded Image data.
I want to use this decoded image data to be used as a picture and display as a label/button in tkinter.

For example:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
l=Label(root,image=image=PhotoImage(data=datas)).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

However, tkinter is not accepting the value stored in `data` to be used as an image.
It displays the following error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 23, in <module>
    l=Label(root,image=PhotoImage(data=datas))
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3394, in __init__

    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3350, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize image data
```

Comment: Are you using python2 or python3? According to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27175029/tkinter-will-not-recognize-image-data-in-base64-encoded-string) it seems to be possible with python3.

Comment: @j_4321 I am using Python 3. I have checked that question and it doesn't seem to solve my problem.

Comment: So have you tried the code given in the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27175029/tkinter-will-not-recognize-image-data-in-base64-encoded-string)?

Comment: @j_4321 Yes i have tried and it doesn't help.

Comment: Is there any alternative way of embedding the image in python script other than base64 encoding technique , so that it can be used in tkinter GUI ?

Comment: Thanks. I tried the same code but with a `.gif` and a `.png` and it works in both cases. So the problem is that you background image is a `JPG` and Tkinter does not support this format. Try converting you image to `PNG` or `GIF` and then it should work.

Comment: @j_4321 I have tried , it doesn't seem to work . can you post your code ? I think i'm messing up the encoding part .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tkinter `PhotoImage` class (in Python 3 with tk 8.6) can only read GIF, PGM/PPM  and PNG image formats. There are two ways to read an image:

- From a file: `PhotoImage(file="path/to/image.png")`
- From a base64-encoded string: `PhotoImage(data=image_data_base64_encoded_string)`

First, if you want to convert an image into a base64-encoded string:

```
import base64

with open("path/to/image.png", "rb") as image_file:
    image_data_base64_encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
```

Then use it in Tkinter:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

im = tk.PhotoImage(data=image_data_base64_encoded_string)

tk.Label(root, image=im).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I think that your problem is that you decoded the string with `datas= base64.b64decode(base64_encodedString)` before using it in `PhotoImage` while you should have used `base64_encodedString` directly.

Comment: Indeed the mistake was as you have guessed , I used the decoded value to create the image object . Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Just to correct the very good answer of j_4321, the correct line for `PhotoImage` is :

```
im = tk.PhotoImage(data=image_data_base64_encoded_string)
```

and my solution to write the 'image' string in order to import it after :

```
with open("image.py", "wb") as fichier:
    fichier.write(b'imageData=b\'' + image_data_base64_encoded_string + b'\'')
```

A simple `import image as img` and the image data will be stored in the .exe file with Pyinstaller (`-F` option).