# How to Solve Base64 Image Error When UsingTkinter

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I would like to display a base64 image using tkinter. 
I am running python 3 on a jupyter notebook.

I have done the following, based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42174987/how-do-i-use-the-base64-encoded-image-string-in-tkinter-label):

1. I import a PNG image and convert it to base64 format
2. I try to open it using Tkinter

   ```
   import base64

   with open("IMAGE.png", "rb") as image_file:
       image_data_base64_encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read()) 



   import tkinter as tk
   from PIL import ImageTk, Image

   root = tk.Tk()

   im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(data=image_data_base64_encoded_string)

   tk.Label(root, image=im).pack()

   root.mainloop()
   ```

   And I get the error:

   ```
   OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-34-96dab6b5d11a> in <module>()
         5 root = tk.Tk()
         6 
   ----> 7 im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(data=image_data_base64_encoded_string)
         8 
         9 tk.Label(root, image=im).pack()

   ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py in __init__(self, image, size, **kw)
        92         # Tk compatibility: file or data
        93         if image is None:
   ---> 94             image = _get_image_from_kw(kw)
        95 
        96         if hasattr(image, "mode") and hasattr(image, "size"):

   ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py in _get_image_from_kw(kw)
        62         source = BytesIO(kw.pop("data"))
        63     if source:
   ---> 64         return Image.open(source)
        65 
        66 

   ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in open(fp, mode)
      2655         warnings.warn(message)
      2656     raise IOError("cannot identify image file %r"
   -> 2657                   % (filename if filename else fp))
      2658 
      2659 #

   OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x000001D476ACF8E0>
   ```

Anyone knows how to solve this ?

Comment: Why not passing `image_file.read()`? or the file name directly?

Comment: Interesting problem. I notice that this error occurs even if Tkinter is not involved. `import base64; import io; from PIL import Image;` followed by `with open("output.png", "rb") as image_file: Image.open(io.BytesIO(base64.b64encode(image_file.read())))` will produce the same error.

Comment: @CristiFati This is just for demonstration, such that people could easily recreate my problem. Actually I have a lot of base64 images stored in a pandas data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the question you have linked to uses the `tkinter.PhotoImage` class, which has a different interface from the `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage` class that your code is using. The latter accepts an ordinary `bytes` object. You don't need to base64 encode it first.

```
import base64

with open("IMAGE.png", "rb") as image_file:
    image_data = image_file.read()


import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = tk.Tk()

im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(data=image_data)

tk.Label(root, image=im).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

Alternatively, keep base64encoding your data, but use `tkinter.PhotoImage`.

```
import base64

with open("IMAGE.png", "rb") as image_file:
    image_data_base64_encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read()) 


import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image

root = tk.Tk()

im = tk.PhotoImage(data=image_data_base64_encoded_string)

tk.Label(root, image=im).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! Actually, I need to use base64 strings, as all my images are given as such.If I replace `ImageTk.PhotoImage` with `tk.PhotoImage(..)`, I get the error: `TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist`

Comment: If I write `root = tk.Toplevel()`instead of `root = tk.Tk()`, it seems to work. The image is displayed.. but also a small empty image is opened.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it's a good idea to replace ImageTk.PhotoImage with tk.PhotoImage. If your data starts out b64encoded, have you tried decoding it? `im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(data=base64.b64decode(image_data))`. Yes, I recognize that this is exactly what the OP of the linked question tried and it didn't work, but he's not using the same classes that you're using.

Comment: Yes, I could do that. However I am worried about the computational time to decode. Why shouldn't I just use `ImageTk.PhotoImage(…)` instead of`tk.PhotoImage(…)`?

Comment: Actually, maybe it _is_ fine to replace ImageTk.PhotoImage with tk.PhotoImage. If I try that on my machine, it works fine, no `TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist` to be seen. I don't think using `root = tk.Toplevel()` has anything to do with it. You might just have had to run the program twice to flush out some bad cached data or something. Try changing it back to `root = tk.Tk()`.

Comment: Just tried it now and you are right !  Thanks a lot for your help !!

Comment: I think you're going to have to endure computational time to decode whether you decode manually or not. If you don't do it, tkinter will behind the scenes.

Comment: I see. So basically, either way would work. Thanks also for the edit on your answer !